# How can sklearn select categorical features based on feature selection

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

My question is i want to run feature selection on the data with several categorical variables. I have used `get_dummies` in `pandas` to generate all the sparse matrix for these categorical variables. My question is how sklearn knows that one specific sparse matrix actually belongs to one feature and select/drop them all? For example, I have a variable called city. There are New York, Chicago and Boston three levels for that variable, so the sparse matrix looks like:

`[1,0,0]
 [0,1,0]
 [0,0,1]`

 How can I inform the sklearn that in these three "columns" actually belong to one feature, which is city and won't end up with choosing New York, and delete Chicago and Boston?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. The feature selection routines in scikit-learn will consider the dummy variables independently of each other. This means they can "trim" the domains of categorical variables down to the values that matter for prediction.

Comment: i see but it is just too bad which makes it not as flexible as R :(

Comment: Then use R or write the feature selector yourself, the simplest idea being to select the whole group of one-hot encoded features if one of them is selected (with the problem that it may become difficult to control exact numbers of selected features and it may get weird if your classes have very different numbers of elements). Or, as @larsmans points out, just go with what the feature selector does if you only care about predictive scores and your next processing step works on one-hot encodings as well.